# iphone (Safari) does not centering FontAwesome icons

Tags: css, iphone, font-awesome

I have a simple button styled with a FontAwesome icon.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    .myButton {
        width: 34px;
        height: 34px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 0;
        color: #357CA5;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        text-align:center;

        /* if I comment out the following line, the arrow will be shown in the middle */
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .myButton:hover {
        background: #357CA5;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="myButton">
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In all browsers the icon will shown in the middle, except of Safari on the Iphone. 
There the icon is on the right.

Other Browsers https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2FXK.png

safari iphone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFxq8.png

If i delete the line

```
font-size: 1em;
```

the icon is shown in the middle.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i have exactly the same issue. Please let me know if you have managed to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Adding these to lines to the div holding the button solved the issue in mobile Safari:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
```

So, the entire element ended up as follows:

```
.message-btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: white;    
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #a3c862;
    color: #a3c862;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: 0.1s all ease-in-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, It works on all browsers but IPhone

adding these three line to the class .myButton will solve your issue. I tested it in IPhone. http://plnkr.co/edit/KACcDGP6yt9cPJvF

```
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into this as well.  Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="slider-nav">
    <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-prev">
       <i class="fas fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <button type="button" role="presentation" class="owl-next">
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
.slider-nav button {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 51px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
    -o-transition: .5s all ease;
    transition: .5s all ease;
}
.slider-nav button i {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: thin solid yellow;
}
```

And here's what it looks like in screenshots.  The left is non-ios and the right is ios.  By putting a border around the i, you can see that with ios devices (tablets, phones) it is not within the boundaries of the i tag.  But with others it is.  Interestingly, with Safari on a MAC desktop it works correctly and displays like the screen capture on the left.
[Screencaptures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4dmW.png)

I tried the answers above adding to the CSS but it didn't work for me.

This is on fontawesome 6.2.1.  I tried the following icon as well but it had the same issue.

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33561998)